# Подскажите, где посмотреть описание синтаксиса php - символ #

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
    foreach ($routes as $pattern => $route){
        if(preg_match("#{$pattern}#", $url, $matches)){
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: В документации http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: @ Alexey Ten спасибо за подсказку - плохо искал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае это **ограничитель шаблона** - это может быть парный не буквенный или экранированный буквенный символ. Всё что между этими символами - шаблон поиска.